# php - Laravel Search Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, eloquent, laravel-paginate

I am trying to make Laravel Search and stuck at point of handling **POST** data as an array in Eloquent way

**HTML Form is as**

```
<form>
    <select name="hidArray[]">
       <option name="test">Test</option>
       <option name="test2">Test2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Now, this input has been initialized as **Bootstrap Multiselect**

When i get input as POST request then it has been represented as an array like as below and which is expetced

```
array:2 [▼
0 => "test"
1 => "test2"
]
```

> Now, i want to form **Eloquent** query to get results from database.

I tried like as below:

```
if($request->has('hidArray')){
      $profile->whereIn('hidArray', $request->input('hidArray'));
}
```

But i think, this way it is not working. Is there any other way i can perform this operation?

Comment: you 'think' it is not working ... what makes you 'think' it isn't working?

Comment: @lagbox because i was not getting desired results but with raw sql i was getting results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have exact idea what are you upto but according to what I understood.

You are trying to do something like:

```
$profile = ModelName::where('user_id',$id);

if($request->has('hidArray')){
      $profile = $profile->whereIn('hidArray', $request->input('hidArray'));
}

$profile = $profile->get();
```

Comment: I just want to make sure that the statement that i have written will take care of POST array in WhereIn?

Comment: @Gags So try the solution I gave. after all you have to test it on your own.